# Can I repair the warping in this laminate flooring

Tags: moisture, laminate-floor

So, this post is going to make me look like an idiot, but I'm okay with that.

About 4 months ago, we bought 800 sq ft of laminate flooring (12mm w/backing).

I stored the flooring in my garage, stacked pretty tightly on a few 2x3s to get them off the ground.

Well, on Sunday we had a guy come to install some of it in our dining room, and he couldn't due to the warping.  (I had previously bought in 7 boxes of the laminate to acclimate to the house 3 weeks prior).

Is there anyway to fix the warping somehow, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the flooring is warped with the shape of the 2x3s from sitting on them for months, maybe you can save them by unwarping them.

First I would try setting them on a hard flat surface (like a concrete garage floor).  If sitting on some shape deformed them, the same process should reform them.  Keeping them at elevated temperature (80–110°F) should speed up the process.

If that proves unsatisfactory, perhaps setting them on the "reverse" of what they sat on before:  Create a 2x3 gap underneath where they sat on support before and with the rest of the bottom solidly supported.  The pressure is much less this way so it would take much longer to change shape than they did before.  Presumably it did not take the whole four months to warp, so with a little luck, perhaps they will reform in a matter of a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. However, I would contact the manufacturer (not the dealer where you bought it) and let them know you have been acclimating it and it has "deformed". Tell them about the installer coming to install, but it was too warped for him to install.

Move the wood into your dining room and keep stacked flat. Keep your receipt handy and be polite. If turned down, ask for customer service supervisor. Take pictures and never mention the garage.